# Is there a downloadable preconfigured LAMP stack?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lamp

It seems to me like there was a site several years ago that pre-packaged LAMP stacks in groups of versions that played well together. I've had a difficult time finding that site or any other site like that.

If there isn't a site like that, is there at least a site that has a chart or something that shows stable builds of LAMP stacks?

I am aware of [TurnekyLinux.org](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) but it isn't really what I'm looking for.

Any input or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `yum install httpd php-mysql mysql-server`

Comment: I'm not asking how to install a LAMP stack. I'm asking for a place to download or chart out stable version of LAMP stacks.

Comment: Look at what the distro versions come with. Those are (usually) stable.

Answer (score 4):

Having packages that play well together under linux belongs to the domain of the package manager for your distro.

If you want a one click install, the most common trick i see (under debian) is to: aptitude install phpmyadmin - which should install the lamp stack for you. Otherwise you have to install a group of 8 or so packages.

Comment: nice trick ! i seriously never seen it that way, but it's obviously very sweet way to install that :)

Comment: Is there something similar for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[XAMPP By Apachefriends](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-linux.html)

There you go :-)

or simply (Debian based):

```
apt-get install apache2 mysql-server mysql-client php5 php5-mysql
```

Then you have a fully functional Apache2 Server (DocumentRoot /var/www) and a MySQL 5.1 (as of today Debian Squeeze) Server.

PS: I'm not sure if this is a programming question. Maybe move to ServerFault

Comment: I think you're right, this would be better server at ServerFault. I'll see if I can move it.

Answer (score 1):

Use apt to install or just automate the process with pretty old tasksel.

I found this guide: http://www.computersnyou.com/2012/05/how-to-install-lamp-stack.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Bitnami LAMP Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp)?  We provide completely free, ready-to-run installers, virtual machines and cloud images (AWS/Azure). There are also Windows and Mac versions

Comment: The Bitnami LAMP stacks and AMIs are awesome. With the AMI you find the one you want, use it to spin up a new EC2 instance on AWS and away you go. They also have installers to set up single stacks on an existing server for LAMP, WAMP and MAMP.